# Javascript Function and show global vars

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-javascript-sdk

**I try do this :**

```
<script>
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {  
        if (response.status==='connected') {
            var fb_status="on";
        } else {
            var fb_status="off";    
        }
    });

    alert("ok"+fb_status);

</script>
```

If i put alert inside function , this alert works , by other side , if i put this alert outside , no works

i supose this it´s more or less the same as global vars in php but no have many experience in Javascript

I only need the same i put in the example for detect in a var the result from function but as in the case i put as example , outside function , i try many things but no get results

Regards and thank´s for the help to community

Comment: declare the fb_status variable outside the block and assign required "on" &  "Off" inside the block.

Comment: You are ordering a pizza then trying to eat it before it is delivered!

Comment: That no works i try ........ :(

Comment: In this case, U can use callback function. Please try this link, which answer ur question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522947/fb-getloginstatus-does-not-fires-callback-function

Answer (score 0):

FB.getLoginStatus is async function so when you try getting `fb_status` outside it, you get `undefined` because `FB.getLoginStatus` didn't return any result yet

Comment: Yes, this is why it fails, but what is the *answer* to the question?

Comment: Yes really i need get result of this outside function and with this i can run other functions but no experience in this cases .......

Comment: @Miguel Garcia: Due to the timing issue, you cannot just use a global variable. You need to restructure your code,. Can you show the rest of your example?

Answer (score 0):

As the `FB.getLoginStatus` call is asynchronous, the result only occurs later and is only relevant *inside* the event handler:

e.g.

```
<script>
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) 
    {   
        // This line gets called many millisconds later
        console.log("When I have a status");
        if (response.status==='connected') 
        {
           var fb_status="on";
        }
        else
        {
            var fb_status="off";    
         }
         alert("ok"+fb_status);
    });
    // This line executes long before the callback returns
    console.log("After call");
</script>
```

Check out the console to see the order of events:

- `"After call"`
- `"When I have a status"`

You mention in comments you want to use the value elsewhere. The problem will be the timing as the result you want will only occur later.